# Heat equation of the distance function and Ricci flow

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, geodesic, ricci-flow, mean-curvature-flows

I would like to get more acquainted to with Ricci flow and evolving metrics. Suppose we are given a familly $\{M, g(t)\}_t$ of Riemannian manifolds with time-dependent metrics. **We would like to understand what evolution on the distance function could be set in order to get Ricci flow**.

1. *Suppose that the distance function evolves according to the following modified heat equation:*
   $$ \partial_t d^2_{g(t)}\left(x, y\right) = \frac{1}{2}\Delta^{(t)}_2 d^2_{g(t)}\left(x, y\right) - n, \quad \forall x, y \in M.$$
   Here $d^2_{g(t)}$ denotes the distance square w.r.t. to $g(t)$ and $\Delta^{(t)}_2$ the Laplace-Beltrami operator w.r.t. the 2nd variable and the metric at time $t$, and $n$ stands for the dimension of the manifold $M$.
2. The evolution of the distance function defines a family of metrics such that this equation holds. **What can be said about the metric evolution ?**

Here is an *attempt*.
$$
\partial_t g(t; x)[v, v] = \partial_t \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{d^2_{g(t)}\left(x, \gamma(s)\right)}{s^2},
$$ with $\gamma$ being any curve such that $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. Now, by interchanging limits, we deduce
\begin{align}
\partial_t g(t; x)[v, v] &= \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{1}{s^2} \partial_t d^2_{g(t)}\left(x, \gamma(s)\right) \\
&= \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{1}{s^2}\left(\frac{1}{2}\Delta^{(t)}_2 d^2_{g(t)}\left(x, \gamma(s)\right) - n\right).
\end{align}
But since this holds for any $\gamma$, and since this is a partial (and not total) derivative, we can use a time-dependent $\gamma$ as well. We will use $\gamma^{(t)}(s)$ to be the geodesic with initial velocity $v$ at time $s$ w.r.t. to the metric $g(t)$. [Using the expansion of the laplacian in spherical coordinates](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214772/limited-expansion-of-mean-curvature-of-geodesic-spheres) [(see also)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362268/hodge-laplacian-of-distance-function), we get
\begin{align}
\partial_t g(t; x)[v, v] &= \lim_{s\to 0} \frac{1}{s^2} \left( \Delta^{(t)}_2 d^2_{g(t)}\left(x, \exp_x^{(t)}(sv)\right) - n\right)\\
&=\lim_{s\to 0} \frac{1}{s^2} \left(n - \frac{1}{3}\mathrm{Ric}(t;x)[v, v]s^2 + O(s^3) - n\right) \\
&= - \frac{1}{3}\mathrm{Ric}(t;x)[v, v].
\end{align}
**It seems that the metric is evolving according to the Ricci flow.** *Does this make sense ?* I can not find any reference mentionning this fact. Otherwise, what is wrong in essence?